# How do I validate my inputted password from a textbox in pygame?

Tags: python, python-3.x, validation, textbox, pygame

so im trying to make a multiple choice quiz so this is the code I have done so far but I have no clue as to how I would validate either password for a returning user or for a new user at the moment it does work as it should. I have 2 functions for if the user has already used the program and 2 for if the user is new and needs to make a new account with a username and a password

```
import pygame
import sys

teal= (0,150,150)

#display window
pygame.init()
size=[800,600]
screen= pygame.display.set_mode(size)
screen.fill(teal)
font=pygame.font.SysFont("comicsandms", 72)

pygame.display.update()


#textbox code
def textbox():
    input_box = pygame.Rect(300, 300, 500, 50)
    color_inactive = pygame.Color('lightskyblue3')
    color_active = pygame.Color('dodgerblue2')
    color = color_inactive
    active = False
    text = ''
    done = False

    while not done:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                done = True
            if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                # If the user clicked on the textbox
                if input_box.collidepoint(event.pos):

                    active = not active
                else:
                    active = False
                # change the colour of the textbox once clicked
                color = color_active if active else color_inactive
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if active:
                    #prints the text from the textbox in the python shell
                    if event.key == pygame.K_RETURN:
                        print(text)
                        text = ''
                        done= True
                    elif event.key == pygame.K_BACKSPACE:
                        text = text[:-1]
                    else:
                        text += event.unicode


        # Render the current text.
        text_surface = font.render(text, True, color)
        # Resize the box if the text is too long.
        width = max(200, text_surface.get_width()+10)
        input_box.w = width

        # Blit the text.
        screen.blit(text_surface, (input_box.x+5, input_box.y+5))
        # Blit the input_box rect.
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, color, input_box, 2)

        pygame.display.flip()


#username and password functions
def username():
    usernametext= font.render("username :", True, (100, 100, 175))
    screen.blit(usernametext, (400 - usernametext.get_width() // 2, 240 - usernametext.get_height() // 2))
    textbox()
    #text

def password():
    passwordtext= font.render("password :", True, (100, 100, 175))
    screen.blit(passwordtext, (400 - passwordtext.get_width() // 2, 240 - passwordtext.get_height() // 2))
    textbox()


#new user username and password functions
def newuser():
    usernametext=font.render("please create a username", True, (100,100,175))
    screen.blit(usernametext, (400 - usernametext.get_width() // 2, 240 - usernametext.get_height() // 2))
    textbox()

def newpassword():
    passwordtext= font.render("please create a password", True, (100, 100, 175))
    screen.blit(passwordtext, (400 - passwordtext.get_width() // 2, 240 - passwordtext.get_height() // 2))
    textbox()




def mainscreen():

    #start up
    font=pygame.font.SysFont("comicsandms", 72)
    titletext= font.render("welcome to a-level chem quiz !!", True,(125,0,125))
    screen.blit(titletext,(400 - titletext.get_width() // 2, 240 - titletext.get_height() // 2))
    logintext= font.render("have you got an account?", True ,(0,0,0))
    screen.blit(logintext,(400 - logintext.get_width() // 2, 300 - logintext.get_height() // 2))




    #button for having account
    yesbutton= pygame.Rect(200,350,100,100)
    pygame.draw.rect(screen,[0,200,50], yesbutton)
    yesbuttontext=font.render("yes", True, (0,0,0))
    screen.blit(yesbuttontext, (250 - yesbuttontext.get_width() // 2, 400 - yesbuttontext.get_height() //2))

    #button for not having account
    nobutton= pygame.Rect(450, 350, 100,100)
    pygame.draw.rect(screen,[200,0,50], nobutton)
    nobuttontext=font.render("no", True, (0,0,0))
    screen.blit(nobuttontext, (513 - yesbuttontext.get_width() // 2, 400 - nobuttontext.get_height() //2))

    pygame.display.update()

    done=False
    while done == False:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                done= True

            if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                mouse_pos= pygame.mouse.get_pos()


                #if they already have an account
                if yesbutton.collidepoint(mouse_pos):  
                    screen.fill((30,30,30))
                    username()
                    screen.fill((30,30,30))
                    password()
                    done = True

                #if they are a new user and need to create a username and password
                elif nobutton.collidepoint(mouse_pos):
                    screen.fill((30,30,30))
                    newuser()
                    screen.fill((30,30,30))
                    newpassword()
                    done= True


                    pygame.display.update()


if __name__ == "__main__": 
    mainscreen()
```

any help would be appreciated, thanks :)
sorry that its a really big chunk of code

Answer (score 0):

@groot 1st of all, the header isn't clear. A more appropriate header would be "How to validate passwords in Python." I thought you were talking about Tkinter text fields. Also, the font is "comicsansms" not "comicsandms". After reading your code and question body, I understood. You need to look into I\O in Python. That is the method of reading a writing to files. After you have written the user and password to a file: then your script can locate that file and verify that the user and password exist and that they match. I haven't used this in a long time, so I don't exactly remember how it works, but if you look up "Python I/O" you will find it.

Comment: I was going to make a database to store all the users usernames and passwords rather than reading and writing to files

Comment: @groot How about accessing a MySQL database either on your localhost server or on a free hosting site? I'm sure you can implement PHP and MySQL in Python. Look online for an answer. If you can't find one, I'll help you look.

Comment: Regarding installing config parser, you don't need to, you need to read and write using sys. Path. But anyway, you want databases. Look at my previous comment.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure how you want to store user information, as you currently only store them in variables which only works durring the current instance of the program and disappears after the program is closed, it is for this reason I'll include the following functions for storing userdata, adding it, and verifying it.

```
import io
import ConfigParser


def create_User(username, password):
    config = ConfigParser.RawConfigParser()
    config.add_section('UserInformation')
    config.set('UserInformation', username, password)
    with open('userinfo.ini', 'wb') as f:
        config.write(f)
    print('User: ' + username + 'added to file with password: ' + password)

def check_User(username, password):
    with open('userinfo.ini') as f:
        conf = f.read()
        config = ConfigParser.RawConfigParser(allow_no_value=True)
        config.readfp(io.BytesIO(conf))
        real_Password = config.get('UserInformation', username)

        if real_Password == password:
            return True
        else:
            return False


#create_User('sage', 'password')
if check_User('sage', 'password') != False:
    print ('User Correct!')
else:
    print('User False!')
```

That uses ini which is a simple Config to use, that code is working and should help you out.

Have Fun

Comment: I can't use the module ConfigParser as I am working on my project at school and the school doesnt really like you when you ask them to download more modules